# History of 9 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.*****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Yahrtzeit of Ezra Hasofer and Nechemia ben Chachalia

2)Birth of Jesus according to some

3)Defmation ceremony of Alfred Dreyfus

4)Yahrtzeit of Rav Ezra rebbi in Kabbalah of the Ramban

5)Yahrtzeit of Shmuel Helman Rav of Metz France

Answer (score 2):

The murder of R' Yehosef Hanagid, the son and successor of R' Shmuel Hanagid, along with several thousand other Jews of Granada. This was in the year 4827 (1066).

Answer (score 2):

Yartheit of the 'Jewish Pope' Shimon Peter, who ensured that Christianity would not be confused with Judiasm, thereby creating a clear separation for  Jews to see.

Comment: I've heard of him (some attribute Nishmas Kol Chai to him, though I believe Rashi strongly disagreed). Where does it say that he died on the 9th of Teves?

Comment: I think in a comment to Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim that lists the known fast days and happy days, by 2 Major poseks in the first half of the 1800's, is the first printed mention we have. I think one of them was Rav Frankel of Worms. Rabbi Leiman has a couple of lectures on it but i didn't take notes.

Comment: @Alex do you know where (or if) this attribution is mentioned in seforim?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill: [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33694&pgnum=347) is where Machzor Vitry quotes this attribution and roundly rejects it.